# Why does my login and signup not work or even redirect?

Tags: java, android

I am making a Log in app but the actual log in button does not work. Everything else on the page works such as a counter I have implemented which counts the log in attempts. The counter has a disable button feature once it reaches 0. I have also tried to implement a sign up on the page which should redirect me to a register form, instead my app will just crash, nor will it log me in despite using the correct credentials.

Bellow is the code from the main activity:

```
//creating variables
private EditText Username;
private EditText Password;
private TextView Info;
private Button Login;
private int counter = 5;
private TextView userRegistration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //assigning the variables to the XML id's
    Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.USERNAMEET);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PASSWORDET);
    Info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.INFOTV);
    Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.LOGINBTN);
    userRegistration = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.REGISTERTV);

    Info.setText("Number of attempts remaining: 5");
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //takes in the userinput
            validate(Username.getText().toString(),Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    userRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class));
        }
    });

}


//function to validate the username and password
private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
    if((userName == "admin") && (userPassword == "changeme")){
        //following lets the user into a new activity e.g. redirect
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Averages.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        counter--;

        Info.setText("Number of attempts remaning: " + String.valueOf(counter));
        Log.d("MyApp","I am here: " + Username.toString() + ", ok.");


        if(counter == 0){
            Login.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: the redirect, nothing I do will redirect me to where I want to go

Comment: Point me to the code that doesn't do the job please